# php5-gd shows in "php -i | grep -i gd" but not in phpinfo();

Tags: ubuntu, php5, apt, gd, php5-gd

I am trying to enable GD in my installation of Apache2, PHP5 and MySQL on my Ubuntu server.

I installed php5-gd with:
`apt-get install php5-gd`

And when I run `php -i` I get:

```
gd

GD Support => enabled
GD Version => 2.0
FreeType Support => enabled
FreeType Linkage => with freetype
FreeType Version => 2.4.8
T1Lib Support => enabled
GIF Read Support => enabled
GIF Create Support => enabled
JPEG Support => enabled
libJPEG Version => unknown
PNG Support => enabled
libPNG Version => 1.2.46
WBMP Support => enabled

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
gd.jpeg_ignore_warning => 0 => 0
```

But it does not show up in phpinfo();
I have restarted the server four times and I have tried to restart Apache2 four million times.

Does anyone have any idea of how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `libjpeg62` isn't installed on your server.

Install `libjpeg62`and restart Apache2.

`sudo apt-get install libjpeg62`

Comment: I did not even think about that when I read the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the php being pointed in your apache webserver is the same as the php you are running in your program?

From what I can see, php -i, is actually running phpinfo();.

If you are in doubt:

```
   echo '<?php phpinfo(); ?>' | php
```

Comment: http://www.pastebay.net/1150906?p=serverfault&submit=unlock

Comment: But when I do <?php phpinfo(); ?> in a php-file and run it in the browser it doesn't show.

Comment: In `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load` it sais `LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so`. But when i do `which php5` it sais `/usr/bin/php5`. Does that have anything to do with this?

Comment: What about 'which php'?

Comment: `which php` shows `/usr/bin/php`

Comment: After a little bit of tinkering with Apache2/PHP logs I managed to get a error in my log file. `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/extensions/gd.so' - libjpeg.so.62: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0`

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue in Windows / Apache. Fixed by using the full path in extension_dir

change: `extension_dir = "ext"`

to: `extension_dir = "c:/progra~1/php5513/ext"`

obviously change your path to suit your install folder